# Myfaces CODI with ClientSideWindowHandler - IE9 back button behaviour

Tags: jsf-2, codi

If in my JSF app using CDI and MyFaces CODI, I have a link like this:

```
<h:link outcome="page2" value="Page 2"/>
```

After I click the link and navigate to page 2, prssing the back button in IE9 does not return to the previous page, but just re-renders page2. I can long press on the button to bring up the list of pages and choose the last but one. The top of list is the "Loading..." page used by CODI's window handler.

This happens when MyFaces CODI is configured to use `ClientSideWindowHandler`.

Firefox and Chrome and IE11 work as expected (IE10 not tested). Unfortunately most of the users will be IE9.

I am using the features provided by CODI for window scopes so cannot do without the handler.

Does anyone know of a way to get round this?

Comment: You can use the std. handler which doesn't cover all use-cases.

Comment: Yes, I am using the standard handler. It's not perfect though because if a user does "Open in new tab" (which they frequently do!) they don't get a new windowId. I've partly mitigated this by using a custom renderer for h:link which removes the windowId parameter when target="_blank" is set. Obviously this doesn't help in the user instigated "new tab or window" scenario.

Comment: I would file an issue in their JIRA.